# WCF REST SOAP web service - unauthorized error

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, sharepoint

I get this error. I have WCF REST SOAP web service thats supposed to fetch data from sharepoint list using sharepoint API and output it in json format. it works well on test server but not on iis production server.

> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while p
>   rocessing this request. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientExcept
>   ion: Unauthorized
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery(DataServiceContext co
>   ntext)
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServi
>   ceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServi
>   ceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery1.GetEnumerator()
>      at WCF_SOAP_REST_Service.Service.MapColumnValues_Events(IEnumerable1 items,
>   String language)

how to fix it?

Comment: WCF didn't produce this error - it just returned it to you. Actually, most probably, the exception occured while execurting a request to SharePoint. Something with IIS \ SharePoint settings?

Comment: I have configured the application pool in IIS to spfarm @YeldarKurmangaliyev  but im not sure what SharePoint settings might be causing this.